# FIles are not recognised by Visual Studio when Migrating a Blazor WASM app to a new solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor app that works ok in .Net 5 and I wanted to move it to .Net6 but in a new project (I won't bore you with the reasons).
However, I find that though I have been able to copy paste the server project files over quite easily, copying Blazor .razor, and razor.cs files isn't so smooth.

Its as if the files need to be added 'properly' to the project ... If I just grab the file and copy it over, V-Studio is throwing all kinds of errors. Whereas if I create the file using the 'rightclick - add razor component' and do the same for the class, then simply copy and past the text from the other solution, it works just fine...
Like the project file needs something adding? Doing to it... though I prefer not to mess with that directly...
Is this some kind of foo-bar on my part or is there a simple work around/fix... faced with cutting and pasting a lot of components...

**** EDIT ****
I didn't originally put error screenshots on here because they were difficult to capture and not 'real' errors anyway. e.g. functions such as 'OnInitialized()' and 'OnParametersSet()' that work fine in the other app, being red underlined with 'no reference' errors and the like as if it couldn't find the libs. So as per the comment below I left it overnight and came back to it this morning... only to find all the errors have gone and left behind only the typical 'null' warnings that are new to Net 6. I had thought that it could have been VS just being slow, and had allowed an hour and had re-started it, and posted the question as a 'last thing of the day' hoping to save time today. So it seems to have sorted itself out, albeit overnight. By all means close this question if considered a waste of space or leave it for others to find to understand the issue that it takes some time.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Could it be an anti-virus issue?

Comment: Yes, OK...I'll have to do some screenshots to show the effect. Its late here now so I'll get to it tomorrow... I guess I think it should have just worked too, but this isn't the first time I came across this. Thank you...

Comment: The errors are varied... and aren't 'real' errors anyway... I don't know if they'll help, we'll see. I guess I was hoping someone else might have seen this behaviour...

Comment: Is there any specific error message? Can you provide some screenshots showing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Probably what's happening is that when you copy over a .razor file, the BuildAction property of the file is being set to 'None' and it's not being compiled. If that's the case, changing the BuildAction (of the copied file) to 'Content' should fix it.